# If time stop at Sagittarius A event horizon, can time restart the other way inside?

Tags: black-holes, time-dilation, event-horizon, galaxies

From our point of view in our Galaxy, his center, Sagittarius A, is a super massive black hole. At event horizon of this singularity, gravity stop time.
Is there any reason why time would not run in reverse, on the other side?

Comment: See the upper left spacetime diagram in [MTW, Fig. 32.1](https://i.ibb.co/c2pyTCd/mtw-32-1.png), we do already have a bunch of [postings](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/740537/24093) on that subject.

Comment: It is not gravity which stops time, it's rather mass which expands time. To think in term of flow of time or speed of time is a human perception bias, an illusion. In which dimension a speed of time would be measured?