Are black holes …white holes?
Time dilation is infinite at the event horizon, after all.
As you approach the event horizon, your frame of reference slows asymptotically to match that of the black hole. While the universe around you fast-forwards toward heat death, the Hawking radiation coming out at you blue shifts the closer you get until it is so bright as to be indistinguishable from a white hole.
You’d never cross the event horizon; you’d be disintegrated and blasted outward into the distant future as a part of that very Hawking radiation.
To an external observer, you likewise never cross the event horizon, but instead appear to slow to an ever more redshifted standstill until you evaporated along with the rest of the black hole. There are no contradictions between what they see and what you see.
Following this logic, nothing crosses the event horizon, even space itself. A black hole warps spacetime to the extent there is no “inside” of it. Instead, it’s a shell of energy with an entropy that scales with its surface area. And it’s violently exploding, slowly.
A black hole might be darker and colder than the CMB or as bright and hot as the Big Bang; it’s just a matter of perspective.
What am I missing in this picture?

Hawking radiations do not come from the horizon, see Birrell and Davies (somewhere in the book, I don't have it at hand right now.)

The OP is asking the community to verify his understanding of black holes based on a sketchy description using unproven hypotheses from semiclassical gravity. There is no legitimate physics question here. Voting to close.

@safesphere OP does have misconceptions, but the question in the title can indeed be answered in the affirmative. See e.g. Hawking 1976: Black holes <...> are indistinguishable, for an external observer, from white holes. The irreversibility that appears in the classical limit is merely a statistical effect.

@A.V.S. Be that as it may, this is not what the OP meant based on the body of the question, which compares the Hawking radiation of a black hole to a radiating white hole and concludes both are the same. Hawking did mention this as well in his book, as I recall, so the question what the OP is missing is moot. The fact that astrophysical white holes are indistinguishable from black holes externally is trivial without quoting Hawking, because both have the same external metric. The trouble begins when you try to extend this metric to the inside. This is related to the time reversal we discussed.

@A.V.S. If you reverse the Kruskal time, then the white hole you get is the one from the maximally extended solution. This white hole is unphysical since it is in the infinite past (which didn’t exist) and so nothing can fall to it. It is not an astrophysical object in question here. If you believe the concept of an astrophysical white hole even makes sense, then you should be able to post its Penrose diagram here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/740527 - as ho one else has been able to so far. The attractive, uncrossable anti-horizon is a geodesic incomplete physical singularity.

Your error is here:

As you approach the event horizon, your frame of reference slows asymptotically to match that of the black hole[, and] the universe around you fast-forwards toward heat death.

This is a misunderstanding of a free-falling observer's trajectory through the event horizon. An observer in free fall doesn't see anything special at the horizon, but reaches the interior of the black hole in finite "proper time."
If anything, a falling observer sees the future evolution of the exterior universe as slowed, rather than sped up, because they are being accelerated away from it all of the infalling information about the exterior universe.
Hawking radiation is an observer-dependent effect; a closely related phenomenon is Unruh radiation.  An observer in free fall ("traveling on a geodesic in spacetime") will see less Hawking radiation than an observer maintaining enough acceleration to avoid falling through the horizon.

“If anything, a falling observer sees the future evolution of the exterior universe as slowed, rather than sped up” - The OP did not refer to what a falling observer sees, but instead said, “the universe around you fast-forwards toward heat death”, which is correct. The external universe dies in the cosmological eternity at the moment you reach the horizon. The quoted statement is not an error or misunderstanding, but is correct.

@safesphere Only for particular coordinate choices. You can't make objective claims about the temporal ordering of events that are spacelike separated. "Observer inside the event horizon" and "future infinity of the outside universe" are spacelike separated.

@safesphere I don't quite follow your argument. Can you please elaborate in an answer? If I am misleading the asker (especially since I think I'm not) they deserve a proper answer to set them straight.

@Sten The spacelike separation is irrelevant, because the horizon is lightlike. Plus the Schwarzschild spacetime is globally hyperbolic, meaning it preserves the causal order of events. My comment above is independent of coordinates. Here it is again rephrased for clarity: no  external event is in the future light cone of any event at the horizon. This means that everything outside, up to the heat death of the universe in the cosmological eternity, happens before anything at the horizon. In other words, a black hole is a temporal tunnel beyond the infinite future of the universe.

@rob I only meant to clarify that what you see is not the same as what happens in your coordinate system, because light rays are not coordinate axes. When you fall, you see the universe slowing down, because light slows down near the black hole. Meanwhile, in your coordinate system, the universe speeds up exponentially and hits the cosmological eternity when you reach the horizon. This is why you cannot return - the universe no longer exists in your present, but is in your past, despite you still seeing the light it emitted while it existed. (Sorry, no time to post a full answer right now.)

The statement that "no external event is in the future light cone of any event at the horizon" is true, of course, but the claim that "everything outside . . . happens before anything at the horizon" does not follow and is not a defensible claim for the reasons given above. Global hyperbolicity means causal orderings are preserved, not time orderings of causally disconnected events.

@Sten Well, your claims are not supported by logic, but you are entitled to your opinions like everyone else.

@safesphere I'll respond when you have written your answer. No rush.

@rob I’ve voted to close this question, because there is no physics question here. See my comment under the question. I posted a similar comment earlier, but it magically disappeared. Must be the magical diamond power ;) The OP starts with repeating a published idea by Hawking that evaporating black holes are similar to white holes, then moves onto describing the firewall idea by AMPS in his own words, and finishes by offering “personal theory” suggestions on the spacetime structure inside. There is nothing to answer here. Much better questions have been closed on this site without mercy.

@rob My comments on your answer were not to defend the OP or criticize your answer. What you said was indeed correct, it just wasn’t the same as what the OP said or asked for. It is like he said, cucumbers are green, and you replied, no - tomatoes are red. Both are correct, just talking of different tings. Thus, since your answer doesn’t address the question, and since this question should have been closed in the first place, me posting an answer here would be utterly pointless, sorry :) And one more thing, please feel free to delete any or all of my comments here, if you prefer, I don’t mind.
